# When is bidirectional search unusable?

Tags: algorithms, graphs, shortest-path

Is there any situation that bidirectional search on a graph is not applicable? for example is there any classes of graph that we can only use ordinary Dijkstra's algorithm, and can not use its bidirectional variant.

The graph may be a dynamic graph.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, a simple one is coming to my mind, a dynamic graph where the **search operators are not reversible**, i.e. both predecessors and successors of a node in the graph can not be calculated.

Comment: Thanks. Is there any resources to find more about such graphs.

Comment: Have a look to Principles of Artificial Intelligence (Nilsson 1980), a very good book.

Answer (score 2):

There are no such graphs.
If you have directed tree-like graph - it would make no sense to go from leaves, but... from the root it will work as intended, and from the leaves - it will stop there and wait to meet the previous.
It will be wasteful, but working. In given example, the same applies - it will produce output from one side, from the second it will stop on single vertex, so it will degrade to one-directional, therefore nothing makes bidirectional search unusable.
When you cannot perform search - it does not matter whether it was bidirectional or not, it will not wirk anyway.